# c# разбить pdf файл на отдельные картинки

Tags: c#, pdf, jpeg

какие есть библиотеки чтобы разбить pdf файл на отдельные страницы и сохранить их в виде jpg?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно использовать различные библиотеки.

- `iText` позволяет разделить PDF-документ, но не конвертировать PDF в изображение.
- `GhostScript` позволяет отображать каждую страницу документа в виде изображения.

  gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=png16m -r150 -sOutputFile='[outputfile]' '[inputfile]'

Comment: Покажите пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Этот код можно использовать из консоли windows ?

Comment: Код для ghostscript может быть запущен в консоли Windows (если у вас установлен ghostscript и на вашем пути, конечно)